# How can I pull the manager's manager?

Tags: trigger, custom-field, approval-process, hierarchy

I have a request to build an approval process on a custom object and the request should be routed to the "Director" (ie, the record owner's manager's manager), and it appears the way to accomplish this is with a trigger.

From what I've read, this is what I think I need:

I need to create a 'Director' field on the User object that will populate the manager of the user's manager to reference for the approval.

On the User object, the trigger should fire whenever the Manager != NULL or if the user's manager is changed and update the Director field.

How can I implement this requirement?

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll be able to implement this requirement without any `Apex`. Instead you should be able to use `Process Builder` to retrieve and set this field.

1. Create a new `Process Builder` flow.
2. The process starts when: `a record changes`.
3. Add Object: `User`.

   - Start the process: `when a record is created or edited`.
4. Add Criteria named something like "Manager Changed". Use a formula:

   ```
   OR(
       ISNEW(), ISCHANGED([User].ManagerId)
   )
   ```
5. Add an action to update the record which triggered the flow.
6. Select your lookup field, then set the Type: `Field Reference`.

   - First select the `Manager ID >` option (includes arrow).
   - Next select the `Manager ID` option (without arrow).
7. Save your action and your flow.
8. Activate.